# Understanding orthogonality to the velocity vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My textbook has stated that, "$\vec{T'}(t)$ is more than just a convenient choice of vector that is
orthogonal to $\vec{r'}(t)$; rather, it is the “right” choice." Why is this case? Is $\vec{T'}(t)$ always orthogonal to $\vec{r'}(t)$ in all dimensions?

Comment: It is nice to have the definitions in your question.

Comment: Presumably you've seen a proof that they are orthogonal.  Is there a particular step that you think might not work in higher dimensions?

Comment: Sorry about not including any definitions. As well, I have not seen any proofs, I've tried to understand it visually first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because $\mathbf T$ is parallel with $r'$, and $\|\mathbf T\|$ is constant, with value $1$.

$$0=\frac d{dt}\|\mathbf T\|^2=\frac d{dt}<\mathbf T,\mathbf T>=2<\mathbf T,\mathbf T'>=<\frac{r'}{\|r'\|},\mathbf T'>.$$

So, $<r',\mathbf T'>=0$. This means $r'\perp\mathbf T'$.

Comment: Must $|\vec{T}|$ always be constant for this to hold true?

Comment: @user12712541 According to the definition of $\mathbf T$, $\|\mathbf T\|$ must be 1.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

$\langle\vec {r'},\vec {T'}\rangle=\|\vec{r'}\|\langle\vec T,\vec{T'}\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\|\vec{r'}\|(\|\vec T\|^2)'=\frac{1}{2}\|\vec{r'}\|(1)'=0$

The intuition is that a unit vector can only change along the unit sphere, meaning its (instant) change must be tangent to the sphere, orthogonal to its direction.